# Jquery will not load because it can't be found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html page don't works because my script is not loading. The script I'm using is as follows:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
```

Can you see the problem? I just copied the scripts src from google hosted libraries.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you're testing this using an HTML file on your local file system.  `//` with no protocol specified is assuming `file://` because of this.

Comment: Right, this would work if he were running it from a localhost of some kind.

Comment: I will add that *normally* protocol-relative URL's like this are a good thing, because they'll call the script with `http://` or `https://` depending on what protocol is used to load the page.

Answer (score 3):

You need put http:// before the URL. Try it:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: Omitting `http:` is generally better, because it can infer `http:` or `https:`.  It's just that in this case, it's inferring `file:`, which is not what is wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Only posting to help anyone else who did what i did.  I spent hours trying to figure out why i was getting about a 100 of these errors.  I had forgot i was messing around with ngRoute and had placed `<base href="/">`  in my index.html.  After removing it everything works again.