# Why is this simple content slider not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

I am currently trying to implement [THIS](http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls) very simple content slider however it is not working. Can somebody please tell me what I have done wrong here as I am at a loss.

My current code is below.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
auto: true,
});
});
</script>

<div class="slider">
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="images/slide1.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/slide2.png" /></li>
<li><img src="images/slide3.png" /></li>
</ul></div>

</body>
```

The console errors that I am getting are:

1.
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

2.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.bxslider.min.js:10

3.
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined other.html:16

Comment: you are missing http:// in your src attribute.

Comment: Use web server for your pages or add `http://` scheme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery will not load because it can't be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671994/jquery-will-not-load-because-it-cant-be-found)

Comment: @PatrickEvans no duplicate mate, see who wrote the other one it wasn't me :)

Comment: Questions that ask the same question are duplicates, it does not mean the same person asked the same question. It's to point out that the question has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the page locally. Please add `http://`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my input related to issues you are facing.

1. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

> As Found above path does not conatin **http:** in starting. So include it in src of script.

2. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.bxslider.min.js:10

> Make sure **jquery.bxslider.min.js** exist on root directory where you are running this page.

3. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined other.html:16

> This issue genrally occure when we do not include **jquery.min.js** in html before using $ sign. And currently this js file is not included there.

Make these changes and run it again. This will resolve your issues.