# jQuery sortable links not loading

Tags: html, browser

Trying to use the [jQuery UI Sortable interaction](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default).
In particular,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Opening it in the file

```
C:\Users\moonwalker\Desktop\simplehtml/tasks.html
```

I have Jquery downloaded to my downloads folder.

```
Errors: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/resources/demos/style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND tasks.html:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I'm sure I have some simple linking error or filepath error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why jQuery does not work on my home (local) machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509740/why-jquery-does-not-work-on-my-home-local-machine)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're loading the webpage from your local drive. In that "local drive" scenario, most modern browsers will interpret HTTP/S-agnostic URLs (ie: `//code.jquery.com`) as local file calls, as opposed to http calls. That's why your error says "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND **file**://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" instead of "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND **http**://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js".

You have a couple of options:

- Convert those prefixes into "http://", ie `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`
- If your production site is going to be on an https server, use "https://" instead so the browser won't complain about mixed security, ie `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`
- Set your local system up as a true webserver
- develop on a remote webserver

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671994/jquery-will-not-load-because-it-cant-be-found

Comment: Thank you, the Http: worked. I had tired something similar but apparently I did it wrong before.

Comment: If your production site is going to be on an https server, use https instead so the browser won't complain about mixed security.

Comment: If you have what you need, be sure to mark the most helpful answer as "accepted" (click on the big "checkmark" image).

Answer (score 0):

you need add (specify) HTTP protocol `HTTP`://code..jquery..., because the browser adding `file`:// automaticaly if protocol does not set because you are opening the file in the browser as file, e.g. your file is not running from webserver.